# Selenium sendText

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

I need to preface this with "I am a noob".

In `WatiN` I was able to use `sendText("text");` which would send the whole text rather than typing it out one character at a time which is what `sendKeys()` does. I have looked quite a bit for a `sendText()` option in Selenium and cannot seem to find anything which works.

Is there a `sendText()` option for selenium, if so could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium RC (the older JavaScript-fueled Selenium that is no longer actively developed), there is the [`type()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#type%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

In WebDriver (also known as Selenium 2), there's no such thing. However, you can easily emulate it via JavaScript:

```java
// only if your driver supports JavaScript
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.whatever("something"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'some text'", elem);
```

Comment: I have to ask, however. Why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: I have a test which sends a large amount of text to a text field. The test takes about 6 minutes to run.

Comment: Selenium types in a 2 page Word document into a text area within seconds for me...are you sure this is the reason for your slowdown?

Comment: The document I am sending it is 150 paragraphs. So it is pretty slow. @Slanec, there is no executeScript method in the JavaScriptExecutor.

Comment: @DarthOpto [I beg your pardon?](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

Comment: @Slanec sorry about that, I must have fat fingered something.